# Pandas: How to round the values which are closest to the whole number for the values more than 1?

Tags: python, pandas

Following is the dataframe. I would like to round the values in 'Period' which are closest to the whole numbers. For example : 1.005479452 rounded to 1.0000,  2.002739726 rounded to 2.0000,  3.002739726 rounded to 3.00000, 5.005479452 rounded to 5.0000, 12.01369863 rounded to 12.0000 and so on. I have a big list. I am trying to do so because in later program I have to concatenate this dataframe with other dataframes based on 'period' column.

```
 df =  period            rate
     0.931506849      -0.001469
     0.994520548       0.008677
     1.005479452       0.11741125
     1.008219178       0.073975
     1.010958904       0.147474833
     1.994520548      -0.007189219
     2.002739726       0.1160815
     2.005479452       0.06995
     2.008219178       0.026808
     2.010958904       0.1200695
     2.980821918      -0.007745727
     3.002739726       0.192208333
     3.010958904       0.119895833
     3.019178082       0.151857267
     3.021917808       0.016165
     3.863013699       0.005405321
     4                 0.06815
     4.002739726       0.1240695
     4.016438356       0.2410323
     4.019178082       0.0459375
     4.021917808       0.03161
     4.997260274       0.0682
     5.005479452       0.1249955
     5.01369863        0.03260875
     5.016438356       0.238069083
     5.019178082       0.04590625
     5.021917808       0.0120625
    12.01369863        0.136991
    12.01643836        0.053327917
    12.01917808        0.2309365
```

I am trying to do something like below but couldn't move further.

```
  df['period'] = np.where(df.period>1, df.period.round(), df.period.round(decimals = 4))
```

Comment: Any suggestions please

Comment: @Ben. Please ignore my code. My problem I mentioned in post and expected output mentioned as examples in the post. Please read example and see the dataframe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a function that basically iterates from 1 to whatever the max whole value should be in the dataframe. This should be faster than a solution that just iterates row-by-row, though it does assume that the dataframe is sorted (like in your example).

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "period": [0.931506849, 0.994520548, 1.005479452, 1.008219178, 1.010958904, 1.994520548, 2.002739726, 2.005479452, 2.008219178, 2.010958904, 2.980821918, 3.002739726, 3.010958904, 3.019178082, 3.021917808, 3.863013699, 4, 4.002739726, 4.016438356, 4.019178082, 4.021917808, 4.997260274, 5.005479452, 5.01369863, 5.016438356, 5.019178082, 5.021917808, 12.01369863, 12.01643836, 12.01917808]
    }
)

print(df.head())
"""
     period
0  0.931507
1  0.994521
2  1.005479
3  1.008219
4  1.010959
"""


def process_df(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df_range_vals = [round(period) for period in df['period'].tolist()]

    out_df = df.loc[df['period'] < 1]

    for base in range(1, max(df_range_vals) + 1):
        # only keep the ones in the range we want
        temp_df = df.loc[(df['period'] >= base) & (df['period'] < base + 1)]

        # if there's nothing to change, then just skip
        if temp_df.empty:
            continue

        temp_df.loc[temp_df.first_valid_index(), 'period'] = temp_df.loc[temp_df.first_valid_index(), 'period'].round(0)

        out_df = out_df.append(temp_df, ignore_index = True)

    return out_df


df = process_df(df)
print(df.head())
"""
     period
0  0.931507
1  0.994521
2  1.000000
3  1.008219
4  1.010959
"""
```

Comment: I think you are rounding all the values in 'period' column to whole number. But I dont want that. Please see the example as expected output I mentioned in the post

Comment: Okay, I added comments, so hopefully the two lines of code that are doing all the work make more sense. The example you showed was to round the column "period" if the value is greater than 1. That is the purpose of this line: `df.loc[df["period"] > 1, "period"] = df.loc[df["period"] > 1, "period"].round(decimals = 0)`
You also have in there that you want to round column "period" to 4 decimals, if it's not greater than 1. That is what `df.loc[df["period"] < 1, "period"] = df.loc[df["period"] < 1, "period"].round(decimals = 4)` is doing. If I misunderstood the question, please clarify.

Comment: I want to round the numbers For example : 2.002739726, 2.005479452, 2.008219178....In these three numbers, 1st one is more closer to 2....So I want to round only 1st one and not the rest. Like this way the numbers which are more closer to whole numbers should get rounded..not all.

Comment: Ah, that's very interesting. And a slightly different problem. I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks my friend. Only you understood the problem in this page. It will really help me if i get some help.Thanks

Comment: @Akash, just made those edits. Lemme know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks my friend. Its working. That really helped me a lot. Great man !!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211663/discussion-between-akash-and-caleb-courtney).

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a lambda function. This one will check it the value is greater than one before rounding to whole, otherwise rounding to 4 decimal places for values less than one. I think that's what you seem to want?

```
df['period'] = df['period'].apply(lambda x: round(x, 0) if x > 1 else round(x, 4))
```

Comment: No. this is not I want. Your output is same as mine mentioned in post. But the problem is different. I mentioned in example in the post. Please read example and look for dataframe. I do not want all the values to be rounded.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# Sort so that we know what is closes to whole no
df.sort_values(by=['period'])

# Create a new column and round everything. This is done to do 
# partition effectively
df['round_period'] = df['period'].round()

df_of_values_close_to_whole_number = list(df.groupby('round_period').tail(1)['period'])

def round_func(x, df_of_val_close_to_whole_number):
    return '{:.5f}'.format(round(x)) if x in df_of_val_close_to_whole_number and x > 1 else x

# Apply round only to values closer to whole number.
df['period'].apply(round_func, args=(df_of_values_close_to_whole_number,))
```

Output

```
0     0.931507
1     0.994521
2      1.00548
3      1.00822
4      1.00000
5      1.99452
6      2.00274
7      2.00548
8      2.00822
9      2.00000
10     2.98082
11     3.00274
12     3.01096
13     3.01918
14     3.00000
15     3.86301
16           4
17     4.00274
18     4.01644
19     4.01918
20     4.00000
21     4.99726
22     5.00548
23      5.0137
24     5.01644
25     5.01918
26     5.00000
27     12.0137
28     12.0164
29    12.00000
Name: period, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, I dont want to round all the period values. That I can do it but it will not solve the purpose for later concate program. I want to round the way I mentioned.

Comment: @Akash Do you only want to round where period value is greater than or equal to 1 ?

Comment: For all the values more than 1. I want to round the only numbers which are close to the whole numbers. I have mentioned as example in my post.

Comment: your examples in the post are not clear, when you say round - "the only numbers which are close to the whole number" can you define how close , is 1.8 close to a whole number ?

Comment: For example : 2.002739726, 2.005479452, 2.008219178....In these numbers, 1st one is more closer to 2....Like this way the numbers which are more closer to whole numbers should get rounded..not all.

Comment: i hope you understood the problem. If not, then let me know, I will explain again.

Comment: @Akash try out the solution now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211661/discussion-between-user2077935-and-akash).